# Associated primes in a reduced ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a reduced ring. Show that $\operatorname{Ass}R$ is the set of minimal prime ideals of $R$.

I think that the first inclusion must come from using $\operatorname{Ass}R \subseteq\operatorname{Supp}R$, assuming the ideal is not minimal, and then showing some contradiction. No idea how to prove every minimal prime is associate, since the ring is not necessarily noetherian.

Comment: Would you mind adding the definition of $\text{Ass}(R)$ that you're using to the question? Also this post might help: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0546 especially 10.65.3

Comment: Ass $R$ meaning the associate primes of $R$, that is, $\{P\in \text{Spec }R |P \text{ is the annihilator of an element } r \in R\}$.   No mention of $R$ being noetherian.

Comment: The converse doesn't hold. If $R=K[X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots]/(X_1X_2,X_3X_4,\dots)$, then $\mathfrak p=(x_1,x_3,\dots)$ is a minimal prime which is not associated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $R$ is reduced and $P=\operatorname{Ann}(x)$ is an associated prime, suppose $Q$ is a prime properly contained in $P$.  Then $(x)P\subseteq Q$ implies $x\in Q$. But then $x^2=0$, a contradiction.  So $P$ was already minimal.

The other direction isn't clear to me. In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102784515) they talk about necessary and sufficient conditions for a reduced ring to have the property that all finitely generated ideals of zero divisors to have a nonzero annihilator, so presumably both cases can happen.

I see here that ["weakly associated primes" are exactly the minimal primes in a reduced ring](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0546) though. In that case, minimal primes are obviously weakly associated, because a minimal prime is minimal over $\operatorname{Ann}(1)=\{0\}$.